# I am currently learning about Android services,all the coding part is good,but the manifest gives me the following error

Tags: android, service

Here is my manifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.developers.service.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MyService" >
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=“MyService"
        android:enabled="true”>
    </service>
</application>
```

It gives me the following error:Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "android:name".

Comment: just wondering why you have activity with same name as service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the service the android name should be like this

```
 <service
            android:name=".NameOfService">
</service>
```

It is better to write ful package name and then name of service.

```
 <service
            android:name="packaganame.NameOfService">
</service>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at where the syntax highlighting screws up on this site, and you'll see it

The marks here are not (XML) quotation marks:

```
    android:name=“MyService"
                 ¯

    android:enabled="true”>
                         ¯
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of the first open quote which is right after android:name=. switch input method to English and replace the open quote of "MyService" :)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at your manifest file, here you have written two times `MyService`. The modified code is:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.developers.service.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--<activity android:name=".MyService" >-->
    </activity>

   <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>
</application>
```

This should fix any problems you're having.